# Find list of user by role using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

In my Spring project, I use Spring Security. I have two entities User and Role in relation many-to-many.  I want to get a list of users with Admin role, for example. My entities:

```java
@Entity
public class Usr implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long userId;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
}

@Entity
public class Role implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long roleId;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private UserRole roleName;

    public Role(UserRole roleName) {
        this.roleName = roleName;
    }
}

public enum UserRole {
    ADMIN, EVAL, CANDIDAT 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using JpaRepository:

```
List<Usr> findByRolesRoleName(String roleName)
```

You can use @Query param as well:

```
@Query("select u from Usr u join Role r where r.roleName = :roleName")
List<Usr> findAllByRolename(@Param("roleName")String roleName);
```

Check this website there are good examples: https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa
Or the official documentation: https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-jpa